# How to add playOrder Sequence in pageTarget using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

The playOrder attribute is required on each pageTarget, and navPoint. It provides a means to collate all pageTargets, and navPoints into a single ordered sequence that reflects their order in the normal playback sequence of the book as presented in the spine files.
playOrder must increase by one and continue with navPoint.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">
    <head>
        <meta name="dtb:uid" content="urn:uuid:29d919dd-24f5-4384-be78-b447c9dc299b"/>
    </head>
    <docTitle>
        <text></text>
    </docTitle>
    <navMap>
        <navPoint id="navpoint1" playOrder="1">
            <navLabel>
                <text>Chapter 1</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="ch1.xhtml"/>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="navpoint2" playOrder="2">
            <navLabel>
                <text>Chapter 2</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="ch2.xhtml"/>
        </navPoint>
</navMap>

    <pageList id="page-mapping" class="page-mapping">
        <navLabel><text>Page Mapping</text></navLabel>
        <pageTarget id="page1" value="1" type="normal"><navLabel><text>1</text></navLabel><content src="ch1.xhtml#pg1" /></pageTarget>
        <pageTarget id="page2" value="2" type="normal"><navLabel><text>2</text></navLabel><content src="ch2.xhtml#pg2" /></pageTarget>
    </pageList>
</ncx>
```

Expecting Output:

```
        <navPoint id="navpoint2" playOrder="2">
            <navLabel>
                <text>Chapter 2</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="ch2.xhtml"/>
        </navPoint>
</navMap>

    <pageList id="page-mapping" class="page-mapping">
        <navLabel><text>Page Mapping</text></navLabel>
        <pageTarget id="page1" value="1" type="normal" playOrder="3"><navLabel><text>1</text></navLabel><content src="ch1.xhtml#pg1" /></pageTarget>
        <pageTarget id="page2" value="2" type="normal" playOrder="4"><navLabel><text>2</text></navLabel><content src="ch2.xhtml#pg2" /></pageTarget>
    </pageList>
</ncx>
```

In this case how to code on XSLT.. Please inform me.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:number count="navPoint | pageTarget" level="any"/>` to determine the number and then create the attribute for that element:

```
  <xsl:template match="pageTarget">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">
              <xsl:number count="navPoint | pageTarget" level="any"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The rest can be handled by the identity transformation, see online sample in XSLT 3 at

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvV/1

which does

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="pageTarget">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">
              <xsl:number count="navPoint | pageTarget" level="any"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your source XML has a default namespace (http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/), we will declare it in the stylesheet as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ncx="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/"
    version="1.0">
```

we then count the number of `navPoint` nodes and store them in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="navPointCount" select="count(//ncx:navPoint)"/>
```

and we have an identity template to copy all nodes as well

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

we then match the target node `pageTarget`, this now becomes `ncx:pageTarget` to tell that it is a `pageTarget` node in an ncx namespace

```
<xsl:template match="ncx:pageTarget">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <!-- here, playOrder attribute is being inserted -->
        <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::ncx:pageTarget) + $navPointCount + 1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the whole stylesheet now becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ncx="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="navPointCount" select="count(//ncx:navPoint)"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ncx:pageTarget">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="playOrder">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::ncx:pageTarget) + $navPointCount + 1"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsT).

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302858/how-to-generate-ncx-using-html-in-xslt] can you solve this question